# How to sort a vector in R, keeping names and values

Tags: r, sorting

I have a list like this

```
                    TTestScores

ALQ120              1.5587910512
ALQ130             -1.7682950999
ALQ140              1.9618228701
ALQ150              4.6912035774
AUQ191              3.7440051368
AUQ260              1.4148585857
AUQ270              3.0977853206
ARQ010             -2.2057617248
ARQ020             -2.2057617248
...
```

I want to sort this in decreasing order. I tried

```
sort(as.data.frame(TTestScores))
```

but I got this error :

> Error in `[.data.frame`(x, order(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing =
>   decreasing)) :    undefined columns selected

I also tried this

```
sort(table(as.data.frame(TTestScores))),decreasing = true)
```

which works but it doesn't sort in decreasing order. besides when I use the second syntax, I get the scores as the names of the table which makes it impossible to understand which score belongs to which variable(ALQ120,...).
anybody can tell me how to sort this list having both the name of variables and their scores?

Comment: can you please `dput` your list?

Comment: Can you show the `str(TTestScores)`

Comment: this is the dput result for head of my list    structure(c(16.0453326732974, 11.7342200487212, 5.85424030479952, 
8.23446078314474, 11.2676598899068, 4.95013150402216), .Names = c("Age", 
"SystolicBP", "DiastolicBP", "BMI", "WaistCircumference", "LDL"
))

Comment: this is the str result for head of my list                                                 Named num [1:6] 16.05 11.73 5.85 8.23 11.27 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:6] "Age" "SystolicBP" "DiastolicBP" "BMI" ...

Comment: You have a vector.  Try `data.frame(V1=sort(TTestScores, decreasing=TRUE))`

`

Comment: when I print the typeof(TTestScores) it shows "list".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `dput`, the 'TTestScores' is a `vector`.  We can directly `sort` with `decreasing=TRUE` and create a `data.frame`

```
data.frame(V1=sort(TTestScores, decreasing=TRUE))
```