# How can I keep the column names when I sort a vector?

Tags: r, sorting

When I sort a vector, I lose the names of the columns, as I lose dimnames attribute.

```
> n
         a     b     c     d     e     f
[1,] 0.848 0.865 0.757 0.792 0.854 0.739

> sort(n)
[1] 0.739 0.757 0.792 0.848 0.854 0.865
```

The structures of n and sort(n) are:

```
> str(n)
 num [1, 1:6] 0.848 0.865 0.757 0.792 0.854 0.739
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:6] "a" "b" "c" "d" ...

> str(sort(n))
 num [1:6] 0.739 0.757 0.792 0.848 0.854 0.865
```

How can i keep the column names with their corresponding value?

Comment: Does the answer here work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33166323/how-to-sort-a-vector-in-r-keeping-names-and-values?rq=1

Comment: `n[,order(n[1,])]`

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks for your quick answer.